# Firebase & Angular for an eCommerce application

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've been looking at using Angular JS for a one page eCommerce application and it seems like making a RESTful API for Angular JS is a huge effort.

So recently I have came across Firebase and it seems to make the whole RESTful side of an Angular JS app easy however I am wondering if it is suitable for an eCommerce application or if there are limitations using this?

Any advice would be great before I delve into the Firebase platform.

Thanks, Nick

Comment: did you got any answer for this? Any cons you came across?

Answer (score 0):

Using firebase for e-commerce is ok, there is even complete solution [for building e-commerce apps on top of Firebase using Angular 4](https://github.com/NodeArt/angular-commerce)

There is two caveats in building store using those stack.

1. There is no fulltext search in Firebase, also there is no way to obtain count of elements inside node. It's a huge problem to make pretty common things like pagination, or filter by more then one product attribute in Firebase. In solution above Flashlight used to handle filters and pages - you can read bit more about in that [article, which describes how to use search queries on e-commerce example](https://medium.com/@NodeArt/improving-firebase-database-searching-abilities-with-elasticsearch-f999245e3925).
2. Second problem is about making you store visible for Google. It's more angular, rather then Firebase problem. There is Angular Universal for that purpose, and recently it became part of core Angular.
   But I wasn't able to connect universal with Firebase. It just renders forever, because of continuously open connection to Firebase. And there isn't a lot of universal examples for now.